# Identity Server 4 custom token endpoint, get signingcredential at runtime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, identityserver4

I am implementing a custom token endpoint for my identityserver4 project. The goal is to issue a token based on validation of a more complex credentials model (a separate user database than Identity Server's built in "client/scope" concept) and issue a Jwt token with extra claims added to help with user identity and access rights in my custom api.

My code is something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetCustomApiToken(CustomUserCredentialsModel credentials)
    {

        var customUser = GetCustomValidatedUser(credentials); //validate user from DB


        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ApplicationSettings.SigningKey); // <--- DeveloperSigningCredential ???
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("user", customUser.ToString()) /* extra custom claims */ }),
            Issuer = "my identity server",
            Audience = "my custom api", 
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return Ok(tokenHandler.WriteToken(token));

    }
```

Mind you I have not tested the above completely yet, but something like that should work in Production provided the key is managed in ApplicationSettings.
But it will not work in development where the signing key is added through Identity Server 4's AddDeveloperSigningCredential() extension.

One solution is to add SigningCredentials in configuration for all Dev/Test environements (= hassle).

Can I resolve the signing credential at runtime (as they are set in Program/Startup) ?

(Also, yes I know: don't store the signing keys readable in appSettings, please disregard that for the above example.)

Comment: Any reason why you can't use normal OIDC flows or an extension grant for this? You'll need to use the same key material `identityserver4` uses in order for clients to be able to validate the issued JWTs.

Comment: It's system to system so the callers will have to be able to sign in programatically without user interaction on the client (and no browser, so no cookies). Is that still possible with normal oidc? I was thinking they call the open token endpoint first and then use the token for subsequent calls. The token must include something that lets me identity the logged in client for the subsequent calls.

Comment: Is the client system here a user or service? If the latter then `client_credentials` probably covers your needs and this can be done via the standard token endpoint.

Comment: That would require me to register all the client credentials in the IdentityServer4 store. I have all the client data in another database and want to validate the credentials against this data. Also it does not apply to my case since I am still running legacy IS4, but the newer versions are licensed by client, so having a lot of external client systems integrating with my api will quickly result in the highest licensing tier (>15 clients), which I guess could be fine, but worth considering. –

Comment: In that case you could create an extension grant that uses any authentication scheme and data store that you like but it would still use the `identityserver4` token endpoint and the tokens will be signed automatically using the key exposed via the discovery endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, I read about this in the docs ( https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html ) and I believe this would probably work for my case. I haven't tried it yet, but will consider. Put an upvote on your comment to highlight it, as it is not a direct answer to my original question, but still might be the best consideration for any others with similar requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out, you can inject the ISigningCredentialStore singleton and resolve the signingCredential from there:

```
    private readonly ISigningCredentialStore _signingCredentialStore;
    
    public CustomTokenController(ISigningCredentialStore signingCredentialStore)
    {
       
        _signingCredentialStore = signingCredentialStore ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(signingCredentialStore));
    }   

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomApiToken(CustomUserCredentialsModel credentials)
    {

        var userId = GetCustomValidatedUser(credentials); 
        if (userId == null) return Unauthorized();

        var signingCredentials = await _signingCredentialStore.GetSigningCredentialsAsync();
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("userId", userId.ToString()) /* extra custom claims */ }),
            Issuer = "my IdentityServer",
            IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Audience = "my api",
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = signingCredentials 
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return Ok(tokenHandler.WriteToken(token));

    }
```

This worked for me and the Jwt token generated can be validated just like any token issued by the built in "connect/token" endpoint.